# How to dynamically set an object key in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, joi

How do I create a function where a key of an object is dynamically set from the function

```js
export const validateObjectId = (key: string = 'id'): ObjectSchema => {
  return Joi.object({
    key: Joi.string()
      .regex(/^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i)
      .required(),
  });
};
```

how do I make the key be the key of the object

Comment: I don't understand, you're validating the key property on the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to find a way out using the code snippet below

```js
export const validateObjectId = (key: string = 'id'): ObjectSchema => {
  interface Obj {
    [key: string]: Object;
  }

  const object: Obj = {};

  object[key] = Joi.string()
    .regex(/^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i)
    .required();
  return Joi.object(object);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following:

```
export const validateObjectId = (key: string = 'id'): ObjectSchema => {
    let object: any = {};
    object[key] = Joi.string()
          .regex(/^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i)
          .required();
    return Joi.object(object);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: I just fixed a syntax error (made `object` of type `any` and removed the `var` before `object[key] = ...`), it should be typescript-compliant now. Let me know if it still doesn't work (and what the error is if that's the case)